# In javascript, the replace() method is replacing words that have a part of the actual replace in it

Tags: javascript, string, replace

How do I prevent javascript from replacing sections of words that match a string I'm trying to replace? 
Here's an example of what It's doing:

```
function replaceApple(){
var aString = "apple app";
var replacing = "app";
return aString.replace(new RegExp(replacing, 'gi'),"cool");
}
```

result:

```
coolle cool
```

How can I make it so that it doesn't mess with whole words? So that the result is:

```
apple cool
```

is there a fix for this or does one have to build a function that will loop through each word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str = 'apple app';
replace = 'app';
str = str.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + replace + '\\b', 'gi'), ' is a fruit ');
```

Result

```
apple is a fruit
```

[Play with it on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WJ2Hx/2)

Comment: perfect! This worked. Thank you geoffreak! You are a life saver!

Answer (score 1):

i think you'll have to use a regular expression to match whole words only

```
"apple app".replace(/(^|\s)app(\s|$)/g, 'cool');
```

update:

```
function replaceApple() {
    var aString = "apple app";
    var replacing = "app";
    var reg = new RegExp('(^|\\s)' + replacing + '(\\s|$)', 'gi');

    return aString.replace(reg, "cool");
}
```

Comment: I'm so sorry, I just fixed it. I failed to mention that I'm using a variable as the replacement in the parameters. How would you suggest I use it that way? (I updated question to include what I failed to mention)

Comment: updated my answer... you can use a variable to build your expression

Answer (score 1):

You can use word boundaries to perform a full word match:

```
function replaceApple(){
var aString = 'apple app';

return aString.replace(/\bapp\b/,'cool');
}
```

**UPDATE** - after OP posted some additional requirements

The recommendation is that you don't build RegEx passing a literal string since on literal strings `\` must be escaped; you can instead do this:

```
function replaceApple(replacing) {
  var aString = 'apple app';
  replacing = '\\b'+replacing+'\\b';
  return (aString.replace(new RegExp(replacing,'gi'),'cool'));
}
```

Comment: What if your using it as `RegExp()`? Like the revised code above?